# Is there a classification of subgroups of automorphisms of space?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, transformation

If we start with general (invertable) functions $f:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$. What conditions can we put on them such that they form a group. I can think of a few:

We could restrict the space to a surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ so that $f:S\rightarrow S$. For example f could be **diffeomorphisms of the sphere**. So for $f(x)$ we would have $|f|^2=1$ and $|x|^2=1$. We could restrict S to be only **affine transformations** then we would get the **Lie groups** such as O(N). Or with translations it would be the **Poincaré group**. $f(x)=P+Mx$, with $M^TM=1$.

We could pair up dimensions and functions $\{f(x,y),g(x,y)\}$ and treat them as **holomorphic functions**. $z=x+iy, h=f+ig$. With $\partial_x f - \partial_y g=0$ and $\partial_y f + \partial_x g=0$ etc. So this reduces the function space from $\mathbb{R}^{2N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^N$. (What about for quaternions?)

We could restrict $f$ to be **conformal** angle preserving functions. $f(x)=(ax+b)/(cx+d)$ and its multidimensional generalisations. This is equivalent to the condition $2 f'''(x) f'(x) - 3f''(x)^2=0$

I can't think of any more. It seems to me that most can be derived by specifying some differential equations $L[f]=0$ so that it holds $L[f(g)]=0$ also. Or by specifying a restriction on the space as a subsurface such has $s(x)=0$.

Is there a general classification? (What about also for superspace?)

Comment: I find the contents of this question somewhat strange given the title. None of your example sare automorphisms of vector spaces, and many of them are not automorphisms of whatever structure you give them since you do not require invertibility. All in all, it is very hard for me to see what the title has to do with the content and what role the vector space plays anyway (you seem to mainly care about it as a topological space).

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by superspace?

Comment: OK I've changed the title to just space instead of vector-space. I don't know what you mean "not invertible". Rotations, and diffeomorphisms are invertible as is the Poincare transformations as are conformal maps.

Comment: Right, but you also mentioned holomorphic functions.

Comment: @Tobias Superspace means that you have Grassman dimensions.  So as well as $x_n$ where $x_n x_m-x_m x_n=0$ you also have $\theta_n$ where $\theta_n \theta_b +\theta_b \theta_a=0$

Comment: How are those related to the space? What you write there seems to be some operators or similar, rather than some properties of the space itself. I still hve no idea what would constitute an answer here as it is not clear what sort of maps you would consider (or what you mean by "space").

Comment: OK. That is right. I don't know what type of "thing" a holomorphic function is then. It is a type of restriction of functions on space. But it is not invertible. Does this kind of thing have a name?

Comment: Superspace: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superspace That's just an extra bit of the question not really important.